# How to get simplified form of summation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have this code to calculate the energy of a signal.

```
syms n N
x3(n) = cos(pi/4*n);
x3(n) = abs(x3(n)) * abs(x3(n));
energy = symsum(x3(n),-inf,inf);
vpa(energy)
```

I am getting this output.

```
symsum(abs(exp(-(pi*n*1i)/4)/2 + exp((pi*n*1i)/4)/2)^2, n, 0, Inf) + symsum(abs(exp(-(pi*n*1i)/4)/2 + exp((pi*n*1i)/4)/2)^2, n, 1, Inf)
```

How can i get a simplified output in the form of real number?

I also tried to solve it by using sum instead of symsum for summation but couldn't get desired answer.

Comment: you are using the Symbolic Math Toolbox. If you want to get a numeric value, just don't use it? If you need the formula try `pretty` on the answer to see that it can't get more condensed

Comment: so how to fix it?  should i use another approach to solve this or there is some other way to get a numeric value?

Comment: There are two problems with your code: 1) `symsum` requires in your case `n` as second parameter, 2) your sum with this boundary conditions does not have a finite/real result. Check the math.

Comment: Results remain same even by inserting n as second argument. Secondly its a periodic signal so its energy must be infinity. which is true mathematically.